# How to check folder permissions using pnp/sp library in spfx web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnpjs, reactjs

I am developing one SPFx web part wherein I am showing all the folders which the logged-in user has access to. And I have a couple of folders in one document library(IT Docs) and some of the folders have unique level permissions i.e. those folders are shared with some users.

I am trying to login using admin credentials who have access to all the folders. Now, I have one people picker textbox where I can type the user name, and based on the user selection I want to show all of the folders of that user.

I am able to fetch the folders using the below code:

```
let folders: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("IT Docs")
      .items
      .filter('FSObjType eq 1')
      .select('FileLeafRef', 'FileRef')
      .get();
```

And I want to check whether the folder has permissions to the user which is selected in people picker textbox. Can anybody please suggest me how to achieve the same using pnp/sp library using react js?

FYI, Below is the link which I am referring and using which I was able to check whether the library has permissions to the user but couldn't find the way to check folder has permission to the user. :(
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/permissions/

Please help. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
item.userHasPermissions(LoginName,PermissionKind)
```

to check user permission for the folder item.

Check @pnp/sp/security

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/security/